# Terraform import with for_each from a csv file

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a tfstate.tf file to manage users and groups from Azure Portal.
I have a csv file named "import_groups.csv" which contains some groups like this :

```
"ObjectId","GroupsName"
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[\`"adm-xxx01\`"]"
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[\`"exp-xxx01\`"]"
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[\`"cod-xxx01\`"]"
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[\`"tec-xxx01\`"]"
```

"adm-xxx01" is a string, not an index resource.

I used this command on Powershell to import all the groups into my tfstate file :

```
Import-Csv .\import_groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    terraform import -var-file="./variables/variables.tfvars" azuread_group.$($_.GroupsName) $($_.ObjectId)
}
```

I get the following error for each group :

```
│ Error: Invalid character
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: azuread_group.aad_groups_services[\`adm-xxx01\`]
│ 
│ This character is not used within the language.
```

When I use this other command to import a single group, everything works correctly :

```
terraform import -var-file="./variables/variables.tfvars" azuread_group.aad_groups_services[\`"adm-xxx01\`"] xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Could the problem be linked to the Powershell interpreter ?
Thanks you.

Comment: Fix the formatting in the CSV file, eg. `"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[""adm-xxx01""]"`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen but it doesn't work. It thinks it's an index.

{│ Error: Index value required
│
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: azuread_group.aad_groups_services[adm-xxx01]
│
│ Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.}

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution : another backslash is needed.

```
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","aad_groups_services[\""adm-xxx01\""]
```